# I'd like/want to come, but

Tags: will-would

Friend: John, can you come to the party tonight?

1. John: Sorry, no. I'**d like** to come, but my mum's very ill and I have to look after her.
2. John: Sorry, no. I **want** to come, but my mum's very ill and I have to look after her.

Do they both sound correct?

Comment: What are your doubts?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but (1) is more natural (or "I would have liked to come", implying "if circumstances had been different").

Comment: @KateBunting, Does "I **would like** to come" imply "if my mum **were not** ill"?

Comment: "I would like to come (but I can't because...)"